# Remove columns that contain only zeros in a matrix on Python

Tags: python-3.x, matrix

I am building a matrix on python and once it's built, I would like to remove all the columns that contains only zeros. (Some columns contain zeros but not only so i want to keep them.

```
def remove_column_with_all_zeros(matrix):
    zero_columns = []
    for i in range(len(matrix[0])):
        column = [row[i] for row in matrix]
        if all(val == 0 for val in column):
            zero_columns.append(i)
    for i in sorted(zero_columns, reverse=True):
        for row in matrix:
            del row[i]
    return matrix
```

I tried this function but it doesn't work.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So convert your matrix into np array if it is not:
So this is an example:
Here you would like to remove first column I guess

```
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 4]])
```

So if you have your matrix as the above example you may then do:

```
matrixT = matrix.T
# This will return a boolean that will have True value where all the elements of a column are 0
all_zeros = (matrixT==0).all(1)
updated_matrix = np.delete(matrix, all_zeros, axis =1)
```

Output for my example :

```
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [1, 4]])
```

Let me know if it works for you!!